# In Java how do you convert a decimal number to base 36?

Tags: java, math, decimal

If I have a decimal number, how do I convert it to base 36 in Java?

Comment: A. Base 36 goes all the way from 0 to Z. Imagine it like a hardcore hexadecimal.

Comment: @SOE, it makes no difference how 9 + 1 is <i>graphically/printably represented</i> in base 36. The value that comes after 9 in any base is binary 1001 + 1 = 1010. In hex notation, this value is represented by the printable character 'A', but it could just as well be '%' or '/' even [gulp] the space character.

Comment: Base 42 would have been somewhat more appropriate...

Comment: 26 letters + 10 digits = 36

Answer (score 90):

Given a number `i`, use `Integer.toString(i, 36)`.

Comment: Or use the constant `Integer.toString(i, Character.MAX_RADIX)` I don't imagine it will change any time soon. ;)

Comment: but it *might* change (since its value is not specified), and then the answer would not be base 36, so better stick with plain old Integer.toString(i, 36)

Comment: Have a look at the java code sample on the base_36 wikiepedia site: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36

Answer (score 17):

See the documentation for Integer.toString

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString(int,%20int)

```
toString

public static String toString(int i, int radix)
....
The following ASCII characters are used as digits:

   0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

What is `radix`? You're in luck for Base 36 (and it makes sense)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_RADIX

```
public static final int     MAX_RADIX   36
```

Answer (score 14):

The following can work for any base, not just 36. Simply replace the String contents of `code`.

Encode:

```
int num = 586403532;
String code = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String text = "";
int j = (int)Math.ceil(Math.log(num)/Math.log(code.length()));
for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
    //i goes to log base code.length() of num (using change of base formula)
    text += code.charAt(num%code.length());
    num /= code.length();
}
```

Decode:

```
String text = "0vn4p9";
String code = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
int num = 0;
int j = text.length();
for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
    num += code.indexOf(text.charAt(0))*Math.pow(code.length(), i);
    text = text.substring(1);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps a better name for `code` would be `charset`

Comment: I am sorry but the encoding part is just plain wrong:log(0) is undefined an will fail. log(1) yields 0 and will skip the loop entirely. Every num = code.length^x (e.g 36^1, 36^2, 36^n) will result in "0"

Comment: It fails when entering 1 as value (decoded 1 --> 0)

Comment: Both encode and decode are completely wrong. I don't know why people upvote this.

Answer (score 9):

First you have to convert your number it into the internal number format of Java (which happens to be 2-based, but this does not really matter here), for example by  `Integer.parseInt()` (if your number is an integer less than 2^31). Then you can convert it from `int` to the desired output format. The method `Integer.toString(i, 36)` does this by using `0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` as digits (the decimal digits 0-9 and lower case english letters in alphabetic order). If you want some other digits, you can either convert the result by replacing the "digits" (for example `toUpperCase`), or do the conversion yourself - it is no magic, simply a loop of taking the remainder modulo 36 and dividing by 36 (with a lookup of the right digit).

If your number is longer than what int offers you may want to use `long` (with `Long`) or `BigInteger` instead, they have similar radix-converters.

If your number has "digits after the point", it is a bit more difficult, as most (finite) base-X-numbers are not exactly representable as (finite) base-Y-numbers if (a power of) Y is not a multiple of X.

Answer (score 1):

This code works:

```
public class Convert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num= 2147483647;
        String text="ABCD1";


        System.out.println("num: " + num + "=>" + base10ToBase36(num));
        System.out.println("text: " +text + "=>" + base36ToBase10(text));
    }

    private static String codeBase36 = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    //"0123456789 abcdefghij klmnopqrst uvwxyz"
    //"0123456789 0123456789 0123456789 012345"


    private static String max36=base10ToBase36(Integer.MAX_VALUE); 

    public static String base10ToBase36(int inNum) {
        if(inNum<0) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("Value  "+inNum +"  to small");
        }
        int num = inNum;
        String text = "";
        int j = (int)Math.ceil(Math.log(num)/Math.log(codeBase36.length()));
        for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
            text = codeBase36.charAt(num%codeBase36.length())+text;
            num /= codeBase36.length();
        }
        return text;
    }
    public  static int base36ToBase10(String in) {
        String text = in.toLowerCase();
        if(text.compareToIgnoreCase(max36)>0) {
            throw new NumberFormatException("Value  "+text+"  to big");
        }

        if(!text.replaceAll("(\\W)","").equalsIgnoreCase(text)){
            throw new NumberFormatException("Value "+text+" false format");
        }
        int num=0;
        int j = text.length();
        for(int i = 0; i < j; i++){
            num += codeBase36.indexOf(text.charAt(text.length()-1))*Math.pow(codeBase36.length(), i);
            text = text.substring(0,text.length()-1);
        }
        return num;
    }


}
```

Comment: Try text="ZZ" and it fails. Why?  ZZ is less than max int.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use Integer.toString(Num , base) , for instance, in my case which I needed a 64 bit long variable, you can use the following code:
Using Lists in JAVA facilitates this conversion

```
long toBeConverted=10000; // example, Initialized by 10000
List<Character> charArray = new ArrayList<Character>();
List<Character> charArrayFinal = new ArrayList<Character>();
int length=10; //Length of the output string
long base = 36;

            while(toBeConverted!=0)
            {
                long rem = toBeConverted%base;
                long quotient = toBeConverted/base;
                if(rem<10)
                    rem+=48;
                else
                    rem+=55;
                charArray.add((char)rem);
                toBeConverted=quotient;
            }
            // make the array in the reverse order
            for(int i=length-1;i>=0;--i){
                if(i>=charArray.size()){
                    charArrayFinal.add((char) 48); // sends 0 to fix the length of the output List
                } else {
                    charArrayFinal.add(charArray.get(i));
                }

            }
```

Example:

(278197)<sub>36</sub>=5YNP

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm late to the party, but this is the solution I was using for getting Calc/Excel cell names by their index:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {
    final String base = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    System.out.println(toCustomBase(0, base));
    System.out.println(toCustomBase(2, base));
    System.out.println(toCustomBase(25, base));
    System.out.println(toCustomBase(26, base));
    System.out.println(toCustomBase(51, base));
    System.out.println(toCustomBase(52, base));
    System.out.println(toCustomBase(520, base));
}

public static String toCustomBase(final int num, final String base) {
    final int baseSize = base.length();
    if(num < baseSize) {
        return String.valueOf(base.charAt(num));
    }
    else {
        return toCustomBase(num / baseSize - 1, base) + base.charAt(num % baseSize);
    }
}
```

Results:

```
A
C
Z
AA
AZ
BA
TA
```

Basically the solution accepts any custom radix. The idea was commandeered from [here](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/Recursion/pythondsConvertinganIntegertoaStringinAnyBase.html).

Comment: Nice answer, thanks... now, how do you go backward from a base to an int ? :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the above answers did help but noting 'decimal' and 'to base36' I assume you want to convert a numeric value to base36. And as long as the `Long` value of the raw figure is within (`0 - Long.MAX_VALUE`):

```
String someNumericString = "9223372036854";
Long l = Long.valueOf(someNumericString);
String bases36 = Long.toString(l, 36);

System.out.println("base36 value: "+bases36);
```

output: `39p5pkj5i`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method to convert base 10 to any given base.

```
 public char[]  base10Converter(int number, int finalBase) {
    int quo;
    int rem;
    char[] res = new char[1];

    do {
        rem = number % finalBase;
        quo = number / finalBase;
        res = Arrays.copyOf(res, res.length + 1);
        if (rem < 10) {
            //Converting ints using ASCII values
            rem += 48;
            res[res.length - 1] = (char) rem;
        } else {
            //Convert int > 9 to A, B, C..
            rem += 55;
            res[res.length - 1] = (char) rem;
        }
        number /= finalBase;
    } while (quo != 0);


    //Reverse array
    char[] temp = new char[res.length];
    for (int i = res.length - 1, j = 0; i > 0; i--) {
        temp[j++] = res[i];
    }

    return temp;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be helpful to you.The operation being performed on the 4 digit alphanumeric String and decimal number below 1679615. You can Modify code accordingly.

```
char[] alpaNum = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
     String currentSeries = "";
    int num = 481261;
        String result = "";
        String baseConversionStr = "";
        boolean flag = true;
        do 
        {
            baseConversionStr = Integer.toString(num % 36) + baseConversionStr;
            String position = "";
            if(flag)
            {
                flag = false;
                position = baseConversionStr;
            }
            else
            {
                position = Integer.toString(num % 36);
            }
            result += alpaNum[new Integer(position)];    
            num = num/36;
   }
        while (num > 0);
        
        StringBuffer number = new StringBuffer(result).reverse();
        
        String finalString = "";
        
        if(number.length()==1)
        {
            finalString = "000"+articleNo;
        }
        else if(number.length()==2)
        {
            finalString = "00"+articleNo;
        }
        else if(number.length()==3)
        {
            finalString = "0"+articleNo;
        }
        
        currentSeries = finalString;
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this code from [this](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/convert3.htm) website in JavaScript, and this is my version in java:

```
public static String customBase (int N, String base) {

    int radix = base.length();

    String returns = "";

    int Q = (int) Math.floor(Math.abs(N));
    int R = 0;

    while (Q != 0) {

        R = Q % radix;
        returns = base.charAt(R) + returns;
        Q /= radix; 

    }

    if(N == 0) {
        return String.valueOf(base.toCharArray()[0]);
    }

    return  N < 0 ? "-" + returns : returns;

}
```

This supports negative numbers and custom bases.

Decimal Addon:

```
public static String customBase (double N, String base) {

    String num = (String.valueOf(N));
    String[] split = num.split("\\.");
    if(split[0] == "" || split[1] == "") {
        return "";
    }
    return customBase(Integer.parseInt(split[0]), base)+ "." + customBase(Integer.parseInt(split[1]), base);

}
```

Comment: `(Q-R)/radix` is the same as  `Q/radix` in integer division, given that `R = Q % radix`.

Comment: Good point, because java truncates integers just like `Math.floor`. changing answer. :)