# In Java how do you convert a base 36 number to a decimal number?

Tags: java, math, decimal

Given the base 36 number YPAYPA, is there a library function in Java that would convert this to a decimal number?

Comment: This is very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060921/in-java-how-do-you-convert-a-decimal-number-to-base-36 ... though not the same.

Answer (score 10):

The below returns a String representation, in decimal, of the number.

```
Long.valueOf("YPAYPA", 36).toString();
```

From the [J2SE docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#valueOf(java.lang.String,%20int))

Comment: This converts to an internal Java `long` - to make it a decimal number, you still need to call `toString()`.

Comment: ...and why do you need to convert it to a string?

Comment: Well, in some way you need to present a "decimal"; which is a notation, a symbolic representation of an idea.

Comment: Edited it to use "String.valueOf(long)". One can not call toString() on a primitive long.

Comment: Edited to use `Long.valueOf(String, int)` to get a `Long` rather than a `long`. I expect that's what I initially intended

Comment: Note: This will get a NumberFormatException if the value is greater than Long.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 4):

This will work even on large numbers.

```
new BigInteger("YPAYPA", 36).toString();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is an absolute must if the value exceeds Long.MAX_VAL

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a homework question.  If it's not, then I apologize, but for now I will simply post some information that will help you find the right answer.

Since this is a base 36 number, I will assume that the values are [0-9][A-Z], the values of the letters are A = 10, B = 11, etc.  The easiest way of solving this is through powers.  The position furthest to the right (A in your example) is 10 * (36 ^ 0), which would equal 10.  P would be (15 * 36 ^ 1).

Essentially it is the value of the digit, multiplied by the result of the base raised to the 0-based position it is in.  Our decimal system works exactly the same way (10 ^ 0, 10 ^ 1, etc).