# Program to convert numbers to letters

Tags: java, radix, letters

Im trying to crate a program that does this: A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z AA AB AC AD....ZZ AAA AAB AAC

The way I approached this is hard to put into words but I'll try explaining

I tried creating a base 27 system and make A represent 1, B->2 C->3, and AA->28
The problem is that every 27 letters where I get an @ representing 0.

I also tried making A represent 0 and having a base 26 system but 27 would be BA when I need it to be AA

```
public class aaa 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
{
    int counter=29;
    for(int x=0;x<=counter;x++)
    {   
        int quotient, remainder;
        String result="";
        quotient=x;

        while (quotient>0)
        {   
            remainder=quotient%27;
            result = (char)(remainder+64) + result;
            quotient = (int)Math.floor(quotient/27);

        }
    System.out.print(result+ " ");
           }
    }
}
```

This prints out  A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z A@ AA AB

I want the program to do this A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z AA AB AC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a start, as several answers already mentioned, there are 26 letters, so use a base 26 system, not 27.

Besides that, print A as 0, instead of @, so change `(char)(remainder + 64)` to `(char)(remainder + 65)`. The last thing you need to do is change `quotient = (int)Math.floor(quotient/27);` because you want to print A, that will be 0 in this scale, so subtract 1 from it and stop loop when quotient smaller than 0.

```
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        int counter=59;
        for(int x=0; x<=counter; x++)
        {   
            int quotient, remainder;
            String result="";
            quotient=x;

            while (quotient >= 0)
            {
                remainder = quotient % 26;
                result = (char)(remainder + 65) + result;
                quotient = (int)Math.floor(quotient/26) - 1;
            }
            System.out.print(result+ " ");
        }
     }
}
```

Output (note that there is no space at start of output also):

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z AA AB AC AD AE AF AG AH AI AJ AK AL AM AN AO AP AQ AR AS AT AU AV AW AX AY AZ BA BB BC BD BE BF BG BH
```

Ps: Indent your code correctly!

Answer (score 2):

There are 26 letters from A to Z. Your system is base 26, not 27.

What you'll probably want to do is:

- Start `x` at 1, not 0. Your system is currently representing 0 as an empty string, which may be throwing you off.
- Take the quotient and remainder modulo 26, not 27.
- Add 65 (the ASCII value for `'A'`) to the remainder, not 64 (the ASCII value for `'@'`).

Comment: Java uses Unicode, not ASCII. 65 is the one (for some characters, two are required) UTF-16 code unit value for 'A', a 16-bit number.

Answer (score 1):

There are 26 possible letters, so when you use the `%` and `/` operators, use `26` as the divisor.

`A` has to represent `1`, or else the sequence would be equivalent to:

```
0 1 2 ... 25 00 01 02...
```

However, we would need the range of calculations to be in the range of 0-25.

With modifications to your code, I start with `x` as `1`.

```
int counter=29;
for(int x=1;x<=counter;x++)
{
```

Later on in the `while` loop, I changed it to a `do`-`while` loop, and I subtract `1` from the `quotient` each time, to shift the domain from `1-26` to `0-25`.  Also, I add `65` (`'A'`) to the remainder, so that `0` is mapped to `'A'`.

```
    do
    {
        remainder=(quotient - 1)%26;
        result = (char)(remainder+65) + result;
        quotient = (int)Math.floor((quotient - 1)/26);
    }
    while (quotient>0);
```

Output:

```
A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z AA AB AC
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly. I should've thought of that haha.

Answer (score 0):

Create a char array containing you letter like `char letters[] = new char[]{'A','B', ... }`. write a simple loop like `do ... while(num > 0)`. Mod the number with `letters.length` and add the resulting char to a StringBuilder. Devide the number by `letters.length`. When the loop finishes revers the output and you are done.

**Update:**

```
public class MagicNumbers
{
    private static final char[] LETTERS = { '@', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

    private static final int LLEN = LETTERS.length;

    private static String toMagicString(final int num)
    {
        int temp = num < 0 ? -num : num;

        StringBuilder strB = new StringBuilder();

        do
        {
            strB.append(LETTERS[temp % LLEN]);
            temp /= LLEN;
        }
        while (temp > 0);

        if (num < 0)
        {
            strB.append('-');
        }

        return strB.reverse().toString();
    }


    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {

        for (int i = -28; i < 29; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(toMagicString(i));
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060921/in-java-how-do-you-convert-a-decimal-number-to-base-36) I think there's a simpler approach: Convert the number to base 27, and then replace each character with the appropriate letter (as pointed by Pshemo's comment, you need to define a 'zero' character... I'll assume that `_` will stand for zero). A `HashMap` will hold the custom characters that you want to use to print the number.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class BaseConverter
{
    /**
     * Converts an integer to base 27, and returns the string with the custom characters
     * defined in the map.
     */
    public static String convertToMyBase27(int a) {
        HashMap<Character, Character> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put('0', '_'); // Or another Zero character
        m.put('1', 'A');
        m.put('2', 'B');
        m.put('3', 'C');
        m.put('4', 'D');
        m.put('5', 'E');
        m.put('6', 'F');
        m.put('7', 'G');
        m.put('8', 'H');
        m.put('9', 'I');
        m.put('a', 'J');
        m.put('b', 'K');
        m.put('c', 'L');
        m.put('d', 'M');
        m.put('e', 'N');
        m.put('f', 'O');
        m.put('g', 'P');
        m.put('h', 'Q');
        m.put('i', 'R');
        m.put('j', 'S');
        m.put('k', 'T');
        m.put('l', 'U');
        m.put('m', 'V');
        m.put('n', 'W');
        m.put('o', 'X');
        m.put('p', 'Y');
        m.put('q', 'Z');

        String ans = "";
        String s = Integer.toString(a, 27);
        for(char c : s.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
            ans += m.get(c);
        }
        return ans;
    }
}
```