# Encrypt random 6 digit number -> human readable

Tags: java, encryption, obfuscation

We have numbers from 1 to 999999 we need to encrypt with an easy algorithm. The encrypted output should be human readable characters (A-Z, 0-9) and no longer than 6 digits.

Is it possible with a simple algorith to encrypt the number 123456 to e.g. GH6ZT3 and later decrypt GH6ZT3 to 123456 ?

I only can find examples with Base32 or Base64 encryption, but encrypted output is much greater than 6 digits :-(

Comment: I've seen DNSSEC keys encoded into a human readable form - will post a reference when I find it

Comment: Yes it is. What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: Base64 isn't encryption. If you actually want *encryption*, you'll need a key of some kind. Are you really looking for encryption, or just a different representation for some reason?

Comment: Are you looking for a bijection? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection

Comment: @JonSkeet if we accept ROT13 as weak encryption why isn't Base64 also weak encryption?

Comment: @emory: I wouldn't accept ROT13 as "weak encryption". It's obfuscation, not encryption.

Comment: [Substitution Cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher). **Easy, not Secure**.

Comment: Are you sure you actually want to encrypt the values? What is your goal with this?

Comment: @JonSkeet the line between obfuscation and encryption is gray.  I suspect (given the limitations of the input and output space) that assuming a chosen plain text attack all ciphers are brute-forceable by reasonably sized organizations.  tgoetz should clarify the threat model.

Comment: @emory: I don't think it's particularly grey, to be honest. If there's no secret involved in terms of data, it's obfuscation. If there is, and you can't get the data back without knowing the key, it's encryption. Even if there are edge cases, tgoetz should at least *start* their thinking in those terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to obfuscate these numbers, then it can be done quite easily with a combination of modular arithmetic and base 36 strings.

Here are a couple of functions that will work with any number from 0 to (36<sup>6</sup> − 1):

```
// Convert an integer (from 0 to 2176782335) into a 6-digit string in base 36.
// The result is obfuscated by using modular arithmetic, i.e. multiply by the
// (arbitrarily selected) prime number 1708159939 modulo 36^6 (2176782336)

public static String obfuscate(Long n) {
  Long x;
  x = (n * 1708159939L) % 2176782336L;
  return String.format("%6s",Long.toString(x, 36).toUpperCase()).replace(' ','0');
}


// Inverse of the above function. Converts a 6-character base 36 string into
// an integer value. The number 1553655019 is the modular inverse of 1708159939
// (i.e., 1708159939 * 1553655019 = 1 (mod 36^6)

public static Long deobfuscate(String s) {
  return (Long.valueOf(s, 36) * 1553655019L) % 2176782336L;
}
```

Bear in mind, however, that the obfuscated strings will include every word of 6 letters or fewer. That includes all the [four-letter words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-letter_word).

Answer (score 2):

If you encrypt you want a Human non-readable way to represent the number.

To do what you want, you should change the base of the number. Something as hexadecimal (base 16) should give some good results. Try another base, as 20.

Take a look at: [In Java how do you convert a decimal number to base 36?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060921/in-java-how-do-you-convert-a-decimal-number-to-base-36)

Or, you can choose a [Classical Criptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_cryptography#Classical_cryptography), like in [Ancient Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher). But you will need to change a key with the human that will read. A key, means any word to mix the numbers.