# Translation into another number system JS

Tags: javascript, math, numbers

I have a string and I need to convert this string into another number system.

1959113774617397110401052 - in Decimal notation to thirty-tensary number system (10 to 36).

If i try to use this code:

```
var master = 1959113774617397110401052;
parseInt(master, 10).toString(36);
//8v0wc05bcz000000
```

It doesn't work properly.

Can you help me to know, where is my mistake and how to use this correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: Theres no string in your code...

Comment: As Jonas said, `parseInt` works on strings, but you already have a `number`. However, the number literal `1959113774617397110401052` is greater than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` and thus even `master.toString(36)` won't produce the exact result but something truncated: `8v0wc05bcyyvopvk`

Comment: JS has "only" 53 bits of precision, it cannot store a number that big.

Comment: I'm sorry guys. I have mistake in example code. It's correct example, where master is a string. Sorry
var master = '1959113774617397110401052';
parseInt(master, 10).toString(36);
//8v0wc05bcz000000

Comment: As reference, the result for this input should be `8v0wc05bcz0atee4`.

Comment: A similar older question for Java with answers without using `Integer.toString(number, radix)` is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060921/in-java-how-do-you-convert-a-decimal-number-to-base-36

Answer (score 1):

The maximum integer JavaScript can safely handle is `9007199254740991`. This is what we get if we call `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. Your number, on the other hand, is significantly larger than this:

```js
9007199254740991
1959113774617397110401052
```

Because of this, JavaScript isn't able to safely perform mathematical calculations with this number and there's no guarantee that you'll get an accurate result.

> The `MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` constant has a value of 9007199254740991. The reasoning behind that number is that JavaScript uses double-precision floating-point format numbers as specified in IEEE 754 and can only safely represent numbers between -(2<sup>53</sup> - 1) and 2<sup>53</sup> - 1.
>
> Safe in this context refers to the ability to represent integers exactly and to correctly compare them. For example, `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 1 === Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER + 2` will evaluate to true, which is mathematically incorrect. See `Number.isSafeInteger()` for more information.
>
> — [MDN's notes on `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a multi-precision library like [Decimal.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/#faq) for integer calculations that exceed the range of signed Int32 resp. the continuous integer range representable by 64bit floats. As example:

```js
var astr = '1959113774617397110401052'
var a =new Decimal(astr)
var out = '';
while( a > 0 ) {
    var d = a.mod(36).toNumber();
    a = a.divToInt(36);
    if(d>9) d=d+39; // d+7 for upper case
    out = String.fromCharCode(48+d)+out
}
var my_div = document.getElementById("my_div")
my_div.innerHTML += astr+" in base 36 is "+out;
```

```html
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/master/decimal.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_div"></div>
```