# By using UUID is it possible to generate a 16 character String?

Tags: java, uuid

I have tried UUID and its generating 32 character string.But I want 16 character unique string

Comment: *character ... .

Answer (score 3):

Since a UUID is 128 bits, 128 / 16 = 8, you need to cram 8 bits into each character. So you could express the UUID as a `char[16]` -- but it would not be printable as a string.

ASCII only uses 7 bits, and many of those are non-printable.

You could possibly express an 8 bit number as a String of length 1 by identifying 256 printable unicode codepoints (for example, dingbats, chinese characters etc.) and mapping these to values. This would allow you to display a UUID in an 8-character-wide space on unicode-capable displays. You would probably be able to copy-and-paste these, but care would be needed moving them around - manually typing them would be challenging.

Answer (score 2):

It needs to have 32 characters to be unique.

Lazy way: only tke the first 16 chars (might not always work)

Proper way: find a formula which can break down a 32 character UUID to a 16 character UUID.

Different way: Use the hashcode instead (only works when needing UUID's once)

Answer (score 2):

Another best option by using Apache commons

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(10);
```

above code will generate a random string.
output: ZBgTxJX93f

Reference : https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-generate-a-random-string/

Answer (score 1):

Then don't use UUID.

You can generate a 16 character hexadecimal String from a `long`.

First you generate the `long`:

1. You can maintain some `long` counter (to ensure that the generated identifiers are unique)
2. or generate a random `long` - which runs the risk of getting repeated values.
3. Or use an approach that combines randomness with uniqueness - for example, generate a random number of `k` bits (`k < 64`), and join these bits to `64-k` bits of a unique number obtained from some counter.

Once you have the `long` value, you can convert it to a hexadecimal `String` with `Long.toString(longValue,16)`. Note that you may have to add leading '0' characters to get a 16 character `String`.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not possible to generate 16 character length of UUID**

Because UUID represent 128 bit value.

But can generate 16 character unique string not using UUID.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are different types of [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), corresponding to different usages. The Java SDK UUID allows to process version 1 (timebased) UUID, but unfortunately does not allow to build them. Version 3 and 5 assumes that you already have distinct names, and version 4 is pseudo random. If you have one single generator, you could throw the node indentication away in version 1 UUID and only keep the most significant long. But the risk of collision with a *UID* generated from a different machine would just be the risk of generating it at the same time.

Anyway, expecting a gobally unique identifier on only 64 bits would be highly optimistic, the reason why UUID are 128 bits long

TL/DR: for unique IDs for a single machine, you can safely keep the most significant long from a timestamp based UUID generated with [JUG](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JugHome). If you need several generators, you will have to imagine a dedicated algorithm. [RFC4122](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) would be an interesting reading if you go that way...

Answer (score 0):

Simply not possible: the java [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) represents a 128 bit value - you can't represent that with 16 HEX characters!

You can take the numerical value and print it [base 36](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060921/in-java-how-do-you-convert-a-decimal-number-to-base-36), but that will still not fit into 16 chars (always).

In other words: you have to look into another way, for example by turning *long* values into a string of the desired length.

Comment: You could, however, represent it in 16 Unicode codepoints... I wonder whether OP could work with that?

Answer (score 0):

A GUID / UUID is a 128 bit number often represented as a series of 32 HEX values. A HEX value is base 16. If you want to represent the same 128bit value in 16 digits then you'll need to use base 64 digits.

To do that you'll need to create a mapping similar to how HEX values are mapped. The English alphabet has 26 characters and ASCII has a value for them in both upper and lower case. This gives us 52 distinct digits. Add to that the numerical values 0 to 9 and that brings us to 62. Then you can pick whatever to get you to 64, say '*' and '+', or whatever makes the most sense taking into account their position in the ASCII table. So then you'd create a lookup table that translates between these 64 digits to build a 128 bit value.

This should give you a full 128bit value represented in 16 Base-64 characters. It would look something like:
GaUvr*olp42xgtyu

Note that this is not standard and you'd need to control both the encoder and decoder.

Comment: If you try to encode 128 bit value to Base64, It will not create a 16 character string. To convert 128 bit to 16 char, you will have to pack 8 bits into 1 char. Base64 will only pack 6 bits.